# Filter vector of enums by associated enum using iter() and filter()

Tags: rust, enums

I'm trying to filter a vector of enums by an associated value :

In my case, the enum is `Item`, which got 2 cases:

- `G` containing a `Group` struct,
- and `S` containing a `MetaSegment` struct.

I want to filter a `Vec` of `Item`'s by `G` to get a `Vec` of `Group`'s. In short: from `Vec<Item>` I want `Vec<Group>`. I got this error : `no field 0 on type &&Item` (I tried putting `*` and `**`).

Am I doing something wrong ?

Rust playground : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd87bb6e80396d055653c438e894f41a

The code for reference :

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Item {
    G(Group),
    S(MetaSegment)
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct Group {}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct MetaSegment {}

fn main() {
    let mut stuff = Vec::<Item>::new();
    
    stuff.push(Item::G(Group{}));
    stuff.push(Item::S(MetaSegment{}));
    stuff.push(Item::G(Group{}));
    
    stuff
        .iter()
        .filter(|e| matches!(e.0, Item::G(_)))
        .for_each(|e| println!("'{:#?}'", e));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `matches!(e, Item::Group(_))` (without the `.0`).

However, it still produces an iterator over `Item`s, not `Group`s. You want [`filter_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) instead:

```rust
stuff
    .iter()
    .filter_map(|e| match e {
        Item::G(group) => Some(group),
        _ => None,
    })
    .for_each(|e| println!("{:#?}", e));
```